# React Native App will not launch - react native version mismatch and RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My react native app will not launch. Between the time it launched and didn't launch, I made no major changes, only reloading the app.
 I keep getting this error:

> "React Native version mismatch"

Image of the version mismatch :
[image: Image of the version mismatch]

I have tried looking at posts of similar nature, however none of those solutions have helped.
Occasionally, as I was installing and uninstall various versions of react native to try to fix the app, I came across this error:

> "RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native, missingL accessibilityTraits"

Image of second error :
[image: Image of second error]

What I have tried:

1. updating all packages that I am using for my project
2. uninstalling and reinstalling react-native
3. restarting terminal and computer

Here is my packages.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "1.3.0": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^34.0.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.61.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am using WebStorm as my IDE and testing on an iPhone 7 (physical). I have tried launching the app on other devices, it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

try running this command in your project directory

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.json`, check `expo.sdkVersion` has the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

your version is miss matching in your `package.json` file,
to overcome this problem use the following commands:-

if you are working with npm globally, then use:-

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
```

then,

```
ncu -u && npm install
```

`ncu -u` shows you which version has updated to which version,
[screenshot of output of ncu -u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khhu7.png)

For a specific root folder/project use can use:-

```
npx npm-check-updates -u && npm i
```

then,

```
    ncu -u && npm install
```